# Как склеить 2 листвью в одном скролвью

Tags: android

Нужно разместить 2 лист вью так, чтобы внутри себя они не скроллировались, но скроллировась вьюха в которой они лежат. Попробовал сделать так, но в итоге листвью просто делят экран пополам и скроллятся внутри себя.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/friendsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/contact_item"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/coworkersListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/contact_item"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Не понятно, зачем вам использовать две листвью?

Comment: @Valeriy позже я вставлю между ними текствью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такой задачи, однозначно, нужно использовать один RecyclerView с разными типами элементов списка. [Вот здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/341738/) один из вариантов решения.

**Вкратце:**

1. делаете три класса: friend, coworker, plainText. Все наследуются от
   какого-то одного интерфейса (можно даже без методов)
2. делаете верстку трех типов элементов: friendItem, coworkerItem, plainTextItem
3. делаете три viewHolder: friendViewHolder, coworkerViewHolder, plainTextViewHolder  создаете adapterDelegate на каждый тип элемента списка
4. в адаптере реализуете добавление элементов разного типа в один массив (в той последовательности, в которой вам нужно

В итоге все прекрасно работает в рамках одного списка. А в попытках заставить работать в связке два списка (+ еще что-то между ними) вы потеряете кучу времени (без гарантии корректной работы) и создадите монстра.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы на вашем месте немного переделал логику приложения. Я не критикую ваш выбор, но есть небольшая проблема - android разработка и сами разрабы не советуют размещать вьюхи которые могут скроллится внутри scrollview потому что потом будут проблемы. Текста предупреждения по поводу этого я не нашел. Почему будет проблема - listview имеет свои слушатели жестов скролла а scrollview свои, в итоге listview не будет корректно скроллится или вообще не будет работать нормально. Что бы я вам посоветовал: использовать [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) он обладает всеми необходимыми вам качествами:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <!-- -->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Вот еще [либа](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChildHelper.html) для такого скролла. Вот вопрос [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824542/android-scrollview-inside-another-scrollview-doesnt-scroll) по вашей проблеме. Я настоятельно не советую использовать listview внутри обычного scrollView дабы избежать проблем в дальнейшем. Так же советую посмотреть в сторону RecyclerView со своим адаптером, может он вам больше подойдет для решения ваших задач.